# Slick 3 - Insert into multiple tables, transactionally, based on other table

Tags: database, scala, h2, slick, slick-3.0

What I am trying to do is insert into 3 tables, transactionally, but the latter inserts are based on the first one.

Here are the distinct queries:

```
val personId = persons returning persons.map(_.id)) += Person(occupation)
translatedProperty += TranslatedProperty(languageId, propertyId, propertyName)
personProperties += PersonProperty(personId, propertyId, propertyValue)
```

Now I get the `Seq(propertyName, propertyValue)` from somewhere and iterate over that.

If I insert sequentially, like above, everything works, until it doesn't work, because say the database "crashes". Hence I would like to make above inserts transactionally.

I tried so:

```
val dbAction = (for {
  val personId = persons returning persons.map(_.id)) += Person(occupation)
  props <- (properties.values.map {
    x =>
    {
      val name = x.key
      val value = x.value

      translatedProperties += TranslatedProperty(languageId, propertyId, name)
      personProperties += PersonProperty(personId, propertyId, value)
    }
  })
} yield ()).transactionally

db.run(dbAction)
```

This gives me a compilation error:

> [error]  found   : Seq[Unit]
>   [error]  required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[?,?,?]
>   [error]         props <- (properties.values.map

I then tried with `props = (properties.values.map { ...` (instead of `<-` I used `=`) but to no avail. The person gets inserted, but never the properties.

What am I doing wrong here?

I assume it's because `props` would be a `Seq[FixedSqlAction]` instead of just one?

I should mention that I am using h2 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume it's because props would be a Seq[FixedSqlAction] instead of just one?

Yes, that's exactly the reason.

The solution to your problem would be to simply wrap the `properties.values.map...` part into `DBIO.seq` like so:

```
val dbAction = (for {
  val personId = persons returning persons.map(_.id)) += Person(occupation)
  props <- DBIO.seq(properties.values.map {
    x =>
    {
      val name = x.key
      val value = x.value

     val insertTranslatedProperties = translatedProperties += TranslatedProperty(languageId, propertyId, name)
     val insertPersonProperties = personProperties += PersonProperty(personId, propertyId, value)

     insertTranslatedProperties andThen insertPersonProperties 
    }
  }: _*)
} yield ()).transactionally
```

Also chain the two inner inserts with `andThen` to merge them into one `DBIOAction`